# How can I download iTunes U courses simultaneously?

Tags: itunes, itunes-u

For example, MIT's 18.01 *Single Variable Calculus*, I want do download all the video courses simultaneously instead of clicking each of them(that cute little *free* button), how can I do it?

Comment: I think you can subscribe to it like podcast, and then all content will be listed, and you can multi-select them and download multiple ones.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I have multi-selected them,what to do next?

Comment: Right-click and I believe there would be a menu item that lets you download all of the selected ones.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I tried,didn't find the menu item.